# How to convert keys from spinal case to camel case when using @ConfigurationProperties to assign a map from a YAML file

Tags: java, spring

I have this class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("prefix")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ConfigurationService {
    private Map<String, Object> config;
}
```

It properly reads my YAML file:

```yaml
prefix:
  config:
    spinal-case-key-one: value
    spinal-case-key-two: other
```

But I'd like to convert the keys to camel case before assigning the map. I've read the documentation but found nothing about it. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 2.7 but I'd be happy to know if Spring Boot 3 offers more options.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I also could not find any information about this in the Spring documentation, but even if it is not officially supported, it is still possible by transforming the original map.

You can use this code to transform the map:

```
package com.example.demo;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties("prefix")
public class ConfigurationService {
  private final Map<String, Object> config;

  public ConfigurationService(Map<String, Object> config) {
    this.config =
        config.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(toMap(e -> transformSpinalCaseToCamelCase(e.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getConfig() {
    return config;
  }

  private static String transformSpinalCaseToCamelCase(String key) {
    var words = key.split("-");
    return IntStream.range(0, words.length)
        .mapToObj(
            i -> {
              String word = words[i];
              if (i == 0) {
                return word.isEmpty() ? word : word.toLowerCase();
              } else {
                return word.isEmpty()
                    ? word
                    : Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)) + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
              }
            })
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
  }
}
```

For this to work you have to add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigurationService.class)` to a `@Configuration` class.